# Qt keyPressEvent, "Hold", and keyReleaseEvent Handling with Buttons/Mouse Clicks

Tags: qt, qpushbutton, qevent

I am writing a Qt program to simulate a piece of hardware and I would like to simulate button press, hold, and release events.  In my application, I'd like to handle input from both the keyboard and mouse clicks to make things convenient to the user (i.e. me).  I've noticed some odd behavior and I don't understand it.

The application uses QPushButton with `autoRepeat` enabled and a 100 ms `autoRepeatDelay` and `autoRepeatInterval`.  If I **mouse click** on a button, I receive alternating "pressed" and "released" events.  I would have expected to see 1 to N-1 "pressed" events followed by a "released" event.  Why is Qt behaving that way?

I've also implemented the following code to handle button presses from the **keyboard**:

```
void MyApp::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    QString s = QString("My PRESS key is %1. The counter is %2").arg(event->text(), QString::number(keyCounter));
    qDebug() << s;
    keyCounter++;
}

void MyApp::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    QString s = QString("My RELEASE key is %1. The counter is %2").arg(event->text(), QString::number(keyCounter));
    qDebug() << s;
    keyCounter = 0;
}

bool MyApp::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
        this->keyPressEvent(dynamic_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event));
        return true;
    }
    else if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyRelease)
    {
        this->keyReleaseEvent(dynamic_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event));
        return  true;
    }
    else
    {
        return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
    }
}
```

Here I see two types of behavior.  For alphanumeric keys, I see the alternating "pressed" and "released" events.  For arrow keys, I only see the "released" events.  Again, I would have expected to see 1 to N-1 "pressed" events followed by a "released" event.  Why do the arrow keys behave differently than the alphanumeric keys?

Is what I'm trying to do possible in Qt?

Comment: "If autoRepeat is enabled, then the pressed(), released(), and clicked() signals are emitted at regular intervals when the button is down."  I didn't fully grok this at first - looks like this is the source of the repeated events.  I'll have to generate my own solution.

Comment: behaviour you expected seem in par with windows API... but X11 Gui works diferently... dunno about Wayland. My guess is that qt emulated uniform behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here was my solution:  First I disabled `autoRepeat` and stopped handling `keyPressEvents` because I found that the arrow keys weren't generating them.  Instead I registered shortcuts for the keyboard buttons I wanted to use:

```
QShortcut *shortcutUp = new QShortcut(QKeySequence("Up"), this);
QObject::connect(shortcutUp, SIGNAL(activated()), this, SLOT(on_upButton_pressed()));
shortcutUp->setAutoRepeat(false);
```

Then in the `on_upButton_pressed()` function (for example) I set a flag indicating the button was pressed.  This flag is cleared in the `on_upButton_released()` function.  That flag is checked on a 100 ms interval (using a QTimer).  If the flag is true, I call `on_upButton_pressed()` again.  This means:

- Each mouse click or keyboard button press generates one "Press" event
- The "Press" event sets a flag that is checked by a QTimer
- If the flag is `true`, another "Press" event is generated
- When the mouse or keyboard button is released, the "Release" event is generated and the flag is cleared.

It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by some keys in QT generate auto-repeat event:

> Here I see two types of behavior. For alphanumeric keys, I see the
> alternating "pressed" and "released" events. For arrow keys, I only
> see the "released" events. Again, I would have expected to see 1 to
> N-1 "pressed" events followed by a "released" event. Why do the arrow
> keys behave differently than the alphanumeric keys?

In QT5 you can detect key held down by function `isAutoRepeat()` of `QKeyEvent` object. If the key is held down then `isAutoRepeat()` will return `true`. for example:

```
void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if (event->isAutoRepeat())
    {
        return;
    }

    if (!event->isAutoRepeat())
    {
        qDebug() << "[MainWindow::keyPressEvent()] " << event->key() << "; " << event->isAutoRepeat();
    }
}

void MainWindow::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if (event->isAutoRepeat())
    {
        return;
    }
    qDebug() << "[MainWindow::keyReleaseEvent()] " << event->key() << "; " << event->isAutoRepeat();
}
```